# React, Noob issue

Tags: reactjs

Going through some simple, beginner React challenges and stuck. Apparently I was given enough information to figure this out but can't. Tried many different combinations of code and still not working.

Challenge: The Counter component keeps track of a count value in state. There are two buttons which call methods increment() and decrement(). Write these methods so the counter value is incremented or decremented by 1 when the appropriate button is clicked. Also, create a reset() method so when the reset button is clicked, the count is set to 0.

Note: Make sure you don’t modify the classNames of the buttons.

My code:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }
  };
  // change code below this line

  increment() {
    this.setState({
      this.state.count: this.state.count + 1
    });
  };

  decrement() {
    this.setState({
      this.state.count: this.state.count - 1
    });
  };

  reset() {
    this.setState({
      this.state.count: 0
    });
  };

  // change code above this line
  render() {
    return (

   <div>
   <button className='inc' onClick={this.increment}>Increment!</button>
    <button className='dec' onClick={this.decrement}>Decrement!</button>
    <button className='reset' onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
    <h1>Current Count: {this.state.count}</h1>
  </div>
    );
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you didn't say what wasn't working

Comment: I either pass the test or fail. I'm failing. Not sure what's not working. Does the code look OK? Is there possibly a bug in the challenge curriculum I'm using?

Comment: no your code has syntax errors. `{ something.something: value }` is not legal javascript

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Comment: suggested reading https://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/

Comment: Try opening the JavaScript console and seeing if there are any errors there.

Comment: Blocked script execution in 'https://beta.freecodecamp.org/en/challenges/react/write-a-simple-counter' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not binding `this` to your event handler functions.

Add this to your constructor and it should work.

```
this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this);
this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
```

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.
>
> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions
>   work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without ()
>   after it, such as onClick={this.handleClick}, you should bind that
>   method.

**EDIT: After looking at your codepen, you need to add this line to the bottom of your file:**

```
ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html).

Comment: Thank you but these changes didn't work. Here's a JSFiddle, nothing is even rendering ... https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Answer (score 2):

There are two things I see could be wrong:

1. Not binding your event handlers in the constructor
2. Invalid object syntax in your `setState()`

In your constructor, make sure you use `bind()` on your event handlers so that they have access to the proper `this` context:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this);
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  };
```

When you set state, the object syntax looks wrong. You can't set `{foo.foo: bar}`:

```
  increment() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thank you but these changes didn't work. Here's a JSFiddle, nothing is even rendering ... https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your method calls so that they reference the component instance properly:

```
<button className='inc' onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>Increment!</button>
<button className='dec' onClick={this.decrement.bind(this)}>Decrement!</button>
<button className='reset' onClick={this.reset.bind(this)}>Reset</button>
```

There are other strategies, like binding in the constructor,

```
this.increment = this.increment.bind(this); // etc
```

More [explained in this blog post](https://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/).

Comment: Thank you, but since the code tells me I'm only supposed to touch what's in between the comments, I don't think I'm supposed to touch those. Is there a way I can do this just within the commented section?